# Reportviewer not displaying report properly

Tags: reportviewer

EDIT: I made it so I'm executing a sql statement instead of stored procedure, just for debugging. I now have an error: A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet2'. I also got rid of ReportViewer1.Reset();

I'm trying to figure out why my reportviewer isn't displaying a report like it should after the user clicks on the button "RunReportButton" on Reports.aspx. I have a sql statement that has 2 parameters: @PersonID and @Category. this sql statement searches all records in PersonExercise table that have PersonID = @PersonID And @Category = Category. I execute a dataset based on this sql statement and then pass that into my reportDataSource in the code behind of my reports.aspx.

I then created Report1.rdlc and linked that up to my dataset dsCardio. I dragged ExerciseDate, Distance, Speed from my dataset onto a matrix on Report1.rdlc. When the user clicks on RunReportButton on Reports.aspx then I get the following error: "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet2'". I debugged my code and I saw that thisDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count = 3, which it should. I also have processingmode = local for reportviewer. Any help? Thanks so much!

Here is my Reports.aspx markup that has the reportviewer:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
```

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Cardiovascular</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Weight Lifting</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>


<asp:Button ID="RunReportButton" runat="server" 
    onclick="RunReportButton_Click1" Text="Run Report" Height="27px" 
    Width="84px" />


<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
    Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
    WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" 
    Visible="False">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="Report1.rdlc">

    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>




</asp:Content>
```

Here is Reports.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ExerciseTracker2000
{
public partial class Reports : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    #region Properties

    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public static int personID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Variables

    public int personID = 0;
    public SqlParameter[] SearchValue = new SqlParameter[2];

    #endregion

    #region Page Events

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        personID = CommonMethods.getLoggedInUser();        
    }

    protected void RunReportButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string strCategory = ddlCategory.SelectedValue;
             // strSQL select for orders with no invoices
            strSQL = "SELECT PersonID, ExerciseDate, Category, Exercise, Duration, Distance, Speed";
            strSQL = strSQL + " from dbo.PersonExercise";
            strSQL = strSQL + " where PersonID = " + personID + " And Category = '" + strCategory + "'";

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, connection);

                ad.Fill(ds, "Table0");

            }


            //ReportViewer1.Visible is set to false in design mode
            ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
            SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);


            /* Associate thisDataSet  (now loaded with the stored 
               procedure result) with the  ReportViewer datasource */
            Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource datasource = new
            Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("DataSetCategories_ShowExercisesByCategory", ds.Tables[0]);


            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);

            if (thisDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Sorry, no products under this category!";
            }

            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your Path to the report
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Path = "Report1.rdlc";

EDIT: Nevermind, I see it in the XAML

EDIT2: You call ReportViewer1.Reset(); This is clearing the LocalReport. You have to set the report path again.

Comment: I got rid of Reset() method and now I get the following error: A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet2'. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: I'm Assuming that "DataSet2" is the name of a Dataset in the report object itself. Try ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", ds));